# Is a two-point set a retract of $\mathbb R^3$?

Tags: general-topology

I'm stuck with an example question. Can someone kindly give me some help?

Is a two point set a retract of $\mathbb R^3 $ ?

Comment: Continuous image of a connected space is connected.

Answer (score 6):

The number of path components can only decrease under retractions.

Indeed, if $Y$ is a retract of $X$, then there is a surjective continuous map $X\to Y$, which induces a map from the set of path components of $X$ to that of $Y$ which is surjective.

Answer (score 3):

no, a retraction is continuous and the continuous image of a connected set is connected

Comment: Notice that is is exactly what I wrote.